# Developing for Ubuntu tablet using Python

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

I want to start developing for the Ubuntu tablet, but I don't think that I can use python with the SDK. I heard that you can make games with Python in Blender and I wanted to know if there was a quick and easy way to port games from Blender onto the Ubuntu phone platform and how to do it. If there isn't, are there other ways to make games using Python for the Ubuntu tablet?